# Display Place holder when value is selected using jquery

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-chosen

I want to create a select value that will display the place holder instead of the value of the option.

Ex: when you choose `<option value="">Unselect</option>` it should display the place holder 
"Select Data Type" instead of the value "Unselect"

here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rM88C/6/)

```
<div class="main_wrapper">
    <select data-placeholder="Select Data Type" style="width:350px;" class="myChosen">
      <option value="" selected hidden></option>
      <option value="">Unselect</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
      <br/>
    <select data-placeholder="Select Data Type" style="width:350px;" 
    class="myChosen">
       <option value="" selected hidden></option>
      <option value="">Unselect</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
      <br />
    <select data-placeholder="Select Data Type" style="width:350px;" 
    class="myChosen">
       <option value="" selected hidden></option>
      <option value=""></option> // VALUE NOT SHOWING
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
      <br />
</div>
```

Comment: The question seems to be encrypted.

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Why not just have the blank option with the value "Select Data Type"?

Comment: Want to make it clear for the user that the option will "Unselect" or make the selectbox NULL

Comment: I think it will be apparent to users. It's very common to use "Select" for the null value.

Comment: Users of the form are old people and I'm telling you we are doing this  update for a reason.